multi language tkinter application with widget destruction
I would appreciate your help in this problem that I have, I am creating an app in tkinter in it I navigate between the app destroying widgets to return let's say to a previous page and I call the widgets to advance to another page, the problem is that I am trying to add an option to change the language, and it changes correctly but when moving forward or returning (destroying the widgets) the translation is lost returning to the initial language, I am trying to do them with JSON, this is the code of the language script in which I imported the label that I want to translate from another script:
idioma.py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import json
from main_structure import options_fm


idioma_global = "Ingles"


def cargar_idioma():
    try:
        with open("config.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            return data.get("idioma", "Ingles")  
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "Ingles"


def aplicar_traduccion():
    idioma_seleccionado = idioma_global  
    if idioma_seleccionado == "Ingles":
        ingles()


def ingles():
    from main_matrices import label_datos
    with open("config.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        traducciones = data.get("traducciones", {})
        texto_traducido = traducciones.get("introduced data", "introduced data")  
        label_datos.config(text=texto_traducido)

        texto_select_traducido = traducciones.get("Select", "Select")

        combo.config(values=('Seleccionar', 'Ingles'))


def guardar_idioma(nuevo_idioma):

    try:
        with open("config.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {}


    data["idioma"] = nuevo_idioma


    with open("config.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)



def clicked_2(event):
    global idioma_global  
    nuevo_idioma = id_var.get()
    guardar_idioma(nuevo_idioma)
    idioma_global = nuevo_idioma 
    aplicar_traduccion()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('alt')
id_var = tk.StringVar()
style.configure("TCombobox", fieldbackground="white", background="white")
combo = ttk.Combobox(options_fm, style='TCombobox', width=32, textvariable=id_var)
combo['values'] = ('Select', 'Ingles')
combo['state'] = 'normal'
combo.current(0)
combo.place(x=500, y=10)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", clicked_2)


The JSON file is as follows:
config.json
{"idioma": "Ingles", "traducciones": {"introduced data": "datos introducidos", "Select": "Seleccionar"}}

Help me find a correct way to change the language in tkinter gui
